# how to center items dynamically inside a div

Tags: html, css

given a container with items inside like so:

```html
<div id="container">

    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>   

</div>
```

```css
#container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#container .item {
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrhLt/

Is there a way with CSS (no JS) to automatically center the items with equal margins. Without having to use a table?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code inline so that in the future the question still remains valid and visible for everyone else on the web.

Comment: But also leave the fiddle, easier to answer :)

Comment: sorry, that's a heck of a lot of work :) would be nice if the two played nicely together.

Comment: You mean equal dynamic margins between *each item*, right? If so, I'm answering the wrong question :/

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Adding `text-align:center;` to the container centers all the items.</strike>

You don't want to *use* a table but you can still tell the browser to render it as a table :-) So how about this CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: table;
    border-spacing:20px 0; /* this is the value that controls the margin */
}

#container .item {
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't do it as the margin won't be right. Please post a fiddle if I'm understanding incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question. I have amended my answer.

Comment: Note that the `.item`s are no longer respecting `width: 50px`. Try changing `600px` to anything else.

Comment: @thirtydot agreed, it's a number juggling game between the `border-spacing` and `width` values to constrain the items to the desired width. @AnApprentice, please let me know if the width of the container is variable :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could play with the margins like this:

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;

}

#container .item {
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 1.4%;
    margin-right: 1.4%;
}
```

Play a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zrhLt/9/